# Shapiro.test & plyr: all 'x' values are identical

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I'm trying to run a Shapiro Wilks test on the variable 'Size', using  a dataset that I'm subsetting with ddply (by the variables 'Site' and 'Category'), but I keep getting an error message.

Here's a sample of my dataset (d). I have 4237 observations with 9 categories and 13 sites:

```
Site    Genus    Size    Category
Arn01   ACR        4       ACR
Arn01   ACR        7       ACR
Arn02   ACR        3       ACR
```

I created a function for Shapiro Wilks:

```
shap.w <- function(input){ #shapiro wilk test function 
   if(sum(!is.na(input$Size)) > 3 & sum(!is.na(input$Size)) < 5000){
      p <- shapiro.test(input$Size)$p.value
      return(p)}else{return(NA)} }
```

Then, I try to apply the function to subsets of my data using ddply:

```
sw_test <- ddply(d, .(Site, Category), .fun = shap.w)
```

But when I do, I get an error message that says:

```
Error in shapiro.test(input$Size) : all 'x' values are identical
```

Even though they're clearly not. Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

---

ETA output of

`dput(d[1:20,]):`

```
> dput(d[1:20,])
structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Arn01n", 
"Arn02n", "Arn03n", "Arn04n", "Arn05n", "Arn06n", "Arn07n", "Arn08n", 
"Arn09n", "Arn10n", "Arn11n", "Arn12n", "Arn13n"), class = "factor"), 
Genus = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), .Label = c("ACA", 
"ACR", "AST", "COS", "CYP", "ECH", "FUN", "FVA", "FVT", "GAR", 
"GON", "HEL", "HYD", "ISO", "LEA", "LEO", "LEP", "LOB", "MER", 
"MNT", "MST", "MYC", "PAV", "PBR", "PLA", "PLAT", "POC", 
"POD", "PRE", "PRM", "PRS", "PSA", "SAR", "STY"), class = "factor"), 
Size = c(4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 
2, 3, 3, 6), Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("ACR", 
"FAV", "FUN", "HEL", "ISO", "MNT", "POC", "PRM", "PRS"), class = "factor")), 
.Names = c("Site", 
"Genus", "Size", "Category"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")`
```

---

ETA output of `table(d$Size)`

`1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  33  35  36  37  38  39 
 14 271 525 548 521 424 201 206  50 357  23  95  36   7 171  11  14  30   4 145  11  21   5  46   4   1   5   1  95   1   2  31   3   1   2   1 
 40  41  42  43  44  45  46  48  50  51  53  55  56  57  60  62  63  65  66  70  72  75  76  80  82  83  85  88  90  94  95 100 105 110 120 125 
 80   1   9   3   4  22   1   4  42   1   1   4   1   3  64   3   5   9   4  13   1   2   1  20   2   2   2   1   5   1   2  17   1   2   6   2 
128 130 143 150 155 160 180 200 230 300 890 920 
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143360/discussion-on-question-by-ecologist-shapiro-test-plyr-all-x-values-are-iden).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to the help I received in the comments, I was able to solve this problem by updating the code for the function to read:

```
shap.w <- function(input){           #shapiro-wilks test function 
if(length(unique((input$Size[!is.na(input)]))) > 3 
& length(unique((input$Size[!is.na(input)])))< 5000 ){
p <- shapiro.test(input$Size)$p.value
return(p)}else{return(NA)} }
```

This removes the combinations that are less than 3 / greater than 5000 (although I won't have any greater than 5,000 in this dataset). Once I updated this, the next line ran without any problems. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you return `NA`, then `is.numeric` will give  `FALSE`: Try  `is.numeric(NA)` to see this.

You could return `NA_real_` instead

```
is.numeric(NA)
[1] FALSE
is.numeric(NA_real_)
[1] TRUE
```

It's still an NA though:

```
is.na(NA_real_)
[1] TRUE
```

However, `as.numeric` should also fix that problem (perhaps double check what's being returned to ddply by your function given the inputs)

Comment: Thank you, @Glen_b ! It turns out I was using the incorrect function in the original code. When I updated the function, I get a new error message that says 'Error in shapiro.test(input$Size) : all 'x' values are identical' . I've seen some similar questions on the site, but nothing that seems to fix my problem. I'd appreciate any thoughts you have!